# Guest has not initialized the display ( yet )

Tags: qemu

I have a few virtual machines.

I run them on Arco linux and I use Qemu KVM and Virtmanager.

Everything was fine and all the machines worked fine until now. Now when I'm trying to launch any of the Linux based VMs the Virtmanager just shows the black screen where " Guest has not initialized the display ( yet )" is written.

Nothing changes no matter how long I wait. I've tried installing new Linux based systems, however the same problem appears even there. But my Windows VMs are fine. The settings on both the Windows and Linux VMs are the same. I was wondering whether there is a solution to that problem or do I have to make a fresh install of the system and start all over again?

Comment: I don't know Arco Linux (seems to be a bit niche), so it will be necessary here to tell us all about the versions of virtmanager, qemu, and probably SPICE components

Comment: I'm using Qemu 7.1.0-11, Virtmanger 4.1.0-1, libvirt 1:8.10.0-1.
The SPCIE are standard, everything is the way it's created by default, I haven't touched or tweaked anything.

Comment: does any part of your system require a fee to be paid? ... maybe one of the components has expired a trial period

Comment: Never heard of paying for system components. No, my system configuration is such - laptop with Intel i5 4 cores and Intel graphics, 1050 NVIDIA, 16g of RAM and that is basically all that I have

Comment: @scribre it's pretty common e.g. for Red Hat customers that they pay a subscription fee for Red Hat's support and for specific extensions to the open source software they use.

Comment: i've got the same issue and i found the qemu version was upgrade from 4.2.1 to 6.2.0

Comment: I changed the boot device from <boot dev='hd'/> to <boot dev='cdrom'/> and the prompts no longer shows. By booing from cdrom, i am ok to get into the install page of os. So in my case, it was not simple emulation problem but a problem with os and bios.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case anyone will ever need a solution to such problem - the only option that I've figured out is make a fresh install of the system. After that download all the needed packages again and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

My problem description:

I upgraded my host OS from ubuntu20.04 to 22.04 and some of my guests failed to boot and I can only see `Guest has not initialized the display ( yet )`, by `vnc viewer` and `virtual manchine manager`.

In my case, I have below xml element in my libvirt xml file

```
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-4.2'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/k8s2_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <bootmenu enable='yes' timeout='3000'/>
  </os>
```

My action of deleting file /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/k8s2_VARS.fd solved the problem and guest was brought back again.